# Is the flux through a sphere always null?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics

I tried with different expressions of forces, but when i calculate the surface integral attached to the force and sphere I get a double integral which always leads to $0$. Is there a theorem stating this or am i completely wrong?

Of course forces with the divergence equal to $0$ have the flux $0$ because of the Gauss-Ostrogradski law but for example, this force $F = (xz,yz,-1)$ also has $0$ flux over a sphere.

Comment: You need to ask the question more carefully before it can be answered. If we consider a sphere with a point charge at the centre, then the flux of electric field out through the spherical surface is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have just happened to pick a vector field whose symmetry properties lead to a result of zero for a sphere centered at the origin.  Try a different vector field ($\vec{F} = (x, y, z)$ will do nicely.)  Or integrate your original vector field over a sphere not centered at the origin;  the easiest way to do this is to translate the vector field (rather than the sphere) by replacing $x \to x - x_0$, $y \to y - y_0$, and $z \to z - z_0$.